Is is there any way to convert the geometry values in the overture maps parquet files from binary to postgis compatible point geometry table
I read the places data from overture map downloaded parquet file using duckdb , but all the values are in the geometry column are in binary format, but i am unable to export the data to a postgis table with valid geometry from the overture data read in duckdb, it gives the byte parse error. Can somebody help me out with this. Is there anyway one can convert the data in to a properly formatted  shapefile or geojson with using the bounding box values
I read overture place data parquet file using duckdb spatial extension + I WKB To WKT conversion which failed I tried converting the data to json and then tried ogr2ogr to convert the json to geojson which also failed
